# Issue with chromedriver in RobotFramework

Tags: google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, robotframework

I started with python and Robot Framework.
I'm having this strange exception while trying to run a test case in Robot Framework.

> ```
> WebDriverException: Message: Service chromedriver unexpectedly exited. Status code was: -1073741819
> ```

I tried changing the chromedriver versions, also checked the chrome browser it was updated to the last version.
I'm sure it's in it's place "Python27\Scripts" which is added to the environment variables as well.

Has anyone else had this issue, or know how to solve it?

Comment: Can you paste complete stack trace and version details of selenium, chrome driver and chrome?

Comment: Also the chromedriver version should be compatible with the installed version of Selenium. Please paste here "pip show selenium" (and the other requested info).

Comment: "pip show selenium
Name: selenium
Version: 3.14.0"
"ChromeDriver 2.41" 
"Python 2.7.8"

Comment: it works fine with Mozilla GeckoDriver, but for chrome I get the Exception above